# How to open an excel sheet on click of html hyper link?

Tags: html, struts2

I want to open an excel sheet (.csv file) on click of a hyper link in html.The document will be stored in a folder within the current project root folder.

Comment: Welcome to [stackoverflow] (http://stackoverflow.com/tour) please share what you have tried. then if you got stucked with some exact issue, we will help you. Refer these links for asking proper questions (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , (http://stackoverflow.com//help/mcve) and (http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 1):

```
//for action you need to do following code 

public String execute() throws Exception {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\test.csv"));
        return SUCCESS;
    }

//Struts.xml file need following changes.fileInputStream contains the FileInputStream to be added to struts.xml.

<action name="download" class="com.expertwebindia.action.DownloadAction">
<result name="success" type="stream">
  <param name="contentType">application/octet-stream</param>
  <param name="inputName">fileInputStream</param>
  <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="test.csv"</param>
  <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
</result>
</action>
```

Comment: I implemented this and i am getting run time error from struts.xml

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not find a java.io.InputStream with the name [fileInputStream] in the invocation stack. Check the <param name="inputName"> tag specified for this action.
 at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StreamResult.doExecute(StreamResult.java:237)

Comment: Thank you soooo much creating getter and setter for fileInputStream in action class solved the issue and now i am able to download the file.